# Loading KML tiles generated for Google Earth in Openlayers

Tags: kml, openlayers, tiles, google-earth

first sorry for my english,i have a problem loading a kml file (tiled) into openlayers, the kml file is generated for google earth with this script http://cimss.ssec.wisc.edu/imapp/dbge_v1.2.shtml, you can see an example here: http://modis.umag.cl/desarrollo/kml/2011.09.18.1742.2_3/2011.09.18.1742.2_3.kml , it loads fine in google earth but i don't know how to do it in openlayers, i tried this:

```
var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("KML", {
            projection: map.displayProjection,
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
            url: "http://modis.umag.cl/desarrollo/kml/2011.09.18.1742.2_3/2011.09.18.1742.2_3.kml",
            format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
                extractStyles: true,
                extractAttributes: true,
                maxDepth: 4
            })
        })
    })
```

but is not showing in the map, any ideas??? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following two lines to your code:

```
layer.setVisibility(true);        
map.addLayer(layer);
```

Hope this helps you.If you are getting an error please mention those.It helps us to solve.